# React Native navigation: undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I try to implement a navigation in React Native with react-navigation according to [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) tutorial, but I am facing the following error when launching the app:

undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')
render index.android.js:17:12

**My index.android.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';



export default class Abc extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Button
        title="Go to List"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Liste')
        }
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
export class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to List"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile')
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
export class Liste extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Liste',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Liste"
      />
    );
  }
}
const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Liste: { screen: Liste },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Abc', () => Abc);
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: `navigate.navigate('Profile')`

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf That's irrelevant: he already had `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you wanted to do is to register your `App` component in your `AppRegistry` instead of the `Abc` component.

The reason that you ran into this `undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')` is because the `props.navigation` is not available in your `Abc` component. If you look closely to the bottom of your code,
you have:

```
const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Liste: { screen: Liste },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Abc', () => Abc);
```

So you have created a `StackNavigator` component, but you are not registering this component but instead you are registering the `Abc` component in the `AppRegistry`, and since `Abc` component is not any of the screen under your `StackNavigator`, it won't have access to the `this.props.navigation` thus you would run into the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `Profile` screen.
If you want to go to `Liste` screen from `HomeScreen` use:

```
onPress={() => navigate('Liste')}
```

If you want to go to `Profile` screen then you need to make `Profile Screen` and add it on `StackNavigator`, example:

```
export class Profile extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Profile',
    };
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <Button
                title="Profile"
            />
        );
    }
}
const App = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Liste: { screen: Liste },
    Profile: {screen: Profile},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

almost 3 years since the original question was asked. I had the same problem and landed on this page.

react-navigation is v5 now. The problem I had was because 'navigation' was not passing to the child component.

After a bit more research I fixed the problem using this solution from here.

I need to pass the props to child component like this.

```
<GoToButton navigation={props.navigation} />
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop

Hopefully this helps to new comers like me.